# JQuery Checkbox Copying Values Not Working

Tags: jquery

I wrote this form up, it works fine, except for the checkbox which is supposed to replicate the address values.  No matter, how I write, rewrite, and correct it.  It simply will not work.

The first portion of the code is the form, the second part has the replication portion of code, and the third part is an unrelated mask.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//Any hidden errors that were passed back from 4D?
// for signup forms, we need to see which form we will show the errors on
if ($("#referralForm1").is(":visible")){
    show4DErrors("#referralForm1"); 
}

$("#referralForm1").validate({
    rules: {
        Referral_Name_T: "required",
        Referral_Company_T: "required",
        Referral_Address_T: "required",
        Referral_City_T: "required",
        Referral_State_T: "required",

        Referral_Zip_T: {
            required: true,
            zipCode: true
        },

        Referral_PhoneFull_T: {
            required: true,
            phoneNumber: true
        },

        Referral_Email_T: {
            required: true,
            email: true,

        },
        Referral_EmailConfirm_T: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            equalTo: "#Referral_Email_T"
        },

        Referral_PayToName_T: "required",
        Referral_PayToAddress_T: "required",
        Referral_PayToCity_T: "required",
        Referral_PayToState_T: "required",

        Referral_PayToZip_T: {
            required: true,
            zipCode: true
        },

    }
});


$("Referral_SameAsAbove_T").click(function(){ 
    if ($("Referral_SameAsAbove_T").is(':checked')) 
    { 
        // Checked, copy values 
        $("#Referral_PayToAddress_T").val($("#Referral_Address_T").val()); 
        $("#Referral_PayToCity_T").val($("#Referral_City_T").val()); 
        $("#Referral_PayToState_T").val($("#Referral_State_T").val()); 
        $("#Referral_PayToZip_T").val($("#Referral_Zip_T").val()); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        // Clear on uncheck 
        $("#Referral_Address_T").val(""); 
        $("#Referral_City_T").val(""); 
        $("#Referral_State_T").val(""); 
    } 
}); 




//Mask Setup
$('#Referral_PhoneFull_T').mask('(999) 999-9999');
$('#Referral_Zip_T').mask('99999');
$('#Referral_PayToZip_T').mask('99999');
```

});

Comment: can you provide with a jsFiddle or perhaps show the HTML-code? could be something simple as a typo

Comment: you're doing it wrong ... `$("Referral_SameAsAbove_T")`, you just told jQuery to grab an element with the TAG NAME Referral_SameAsAbove_T. Don't you need a "#"? also, inside a click code, you can refer to the element clicked as `$(this)` and instead of grabbing "click" event on a checkbox, try its [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your selector is wrong

```
$("Referral_SameAsAbove_T")

If it is a class then supposed to be   $(".Referral_SameAsAbove_T") // prepended by a dot

If it is a id then supposed to be   $("#Referral_SameAsAbove_T") // prepended by a pound
```

**EDIT**

Handle the change event for the textbox..

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('change' , function() {
    if ($("Referral_SameAsAbove_T").is(':checked')) {
         if( this.id.indexOf('Address') > -1){
            $("#Referral_PayToAddress_T").val($(this).val());
         }

          if( this.id.indexOf('City') > -1){
            $("#Referral_PayToCity_T").val($(this).val());
         }
       // Other textbox conditions here

    }
    else{
        $(this).val('');
    }

});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/q7f9a/)

NOTE :  This is just to handle the change event for PayToAddress_T textbox. For other's

Comment: It's working now, I didn't have an ID field on the HTML page.  Now I'm trying to get the values to change from the top portion of the from to the bottom if the checkbox is checked.

Comment: Are they not getting copied over??

Comment: Basically everything is getting copied over. But lets say the address 11215 Bob St. and the box is checked, and the user changes it to 11213 Bob St. I want that to change, but I can't figure that out.

Comment: You need to handle that again in the change event for the textbox you are talking about

Comment: So do I have to do that for all 8 textboxes? The ones I want to change, and the ones I want to change, or do I just apply change event to the checkbox?

Comment: Is this in place of this?

    $("#Referral_SameAsAbove_T").click(function(){ 
        if ($("#Referral_SameAsAbove_T").is(':checked')) 
        { 
            // Checked, copy values 
            $("#Referral_PayToAddress_T").val($("#Referral_Address_T").val()); 
            $("#Referral_PayToCity_T").val($("#Referral_City_T").val()); 
            $("#Referral_PayToState_T").val($("#Referral_State_T").val()); 
   $("#Referral_PayToZip_T").val($("#Referral_Zip_T").val()); 
        } 
        else 
        {

Comment: nope.. That one stays as it is for the Checkbox click event .. The one I have written is for the textbox change event .. If the address changes

Comment: I edited it based on your example to fit the other 2 fields in, and then I copied it after the brackets of the Click Event area, and pasted it into there.  I'm in Dreamweaver, and there are no errors.  When I test it on my server, neither functionality works the copy down or the change event.

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle for this

Comment: Do I need to change the " Address " in quotations to ReferralAddress_T? What is a fiddle? I'm new here.

Comment: Thank you, for that. If I wanted to change it up so

$('input[type="text"]').on('change' , function() {

is 

'code'$("#Referral_Address_T,#Referral_City_T,#_Referral_State_T,#Referral_Zip_T).on('change' , function() {'code'

Would I take the following If statement and

if( this.id.indexOf('Address') > -1){
            $("#Referral_PayToAddress_T").val($(this).val());
         }


change address to this or self?

Comment: If I wasn't clear If I wanted to accomplish this in one If.. statement rather than 4 how would I handle the parts with address and referral pay to address?

Comment: I don't think you can do it in one.. If you do that then the wrong value may get copied over to the Textbox